# How to run any existing CodeIgniter project on Xampp?

Tags: php

I am new to CodeIgniter. Kindly tell me how to run any existing project developed using CodeIgniter on Xampp. It has no database. How can I create database for this project?

Comment: Maybe use the MySQL console to create the database? Do you have a SQL file to initialise it? Or are you looking for a migration tool that will create it for you?

Comment: (You may wish to study the CI docs and work through their tutorials. We encourage posters here to make an effort with their questions, and to show what they have tried. If you can edit the question with the same, and do that initial research if you have not done so already, it is much appreciated here).

Answer (score 0):

how to run: open index file in browser or cli.

how to create database- well if you don't have dump, then you are out of luck and only option is to investigate queries and try to replicate tables.